# Dropdown list in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have some huge files which has some 300,000 + Id's and I am able to display the ID's in a dropdown, but it takes a long time to open the dropdown and select the value.

I have created dropdown using the following code:

```
<select asp-for="SelectIDs" asp-items=@Model.pvalues onclick="this.size=1;" onMouseOver="this.size=10;" onMouseOut="this.size=1;" style="padding:10px;position:absolute;">
    <option value="" selected>Select ID..</option>
</select>
```

May I know what needs to be done to handle such huge dropdown lists please?

Comment: Why would you want to select an ID from a dropdown for 300000 items?

Comment: we have set of attributes corresponding to the ID we select in XML file and we need to compare those attributes between two files (Before change and after change)

Comment: *what needs to be done to handle such huge dropdown lists* : you **cannot** seriously expect your users to scroll through up to 300'000 !!!!!!!! entries in a dropdown..... this is a usability **nightmare**. The best way to handle this is **do NOT do this!**. There has to be a better way to handle this scenario - let the user search (incrementally), or something else - but stop wasting your time trying to make the loading of this dropdown fast - rethink your basic assumption that having 300'000 items in a dropdown is feasible - it's **not**!

Comment: You are going to have to expand your question to include a little bit more information around the data that produces 300,000 items. Quite frankly though you cannot expect any interface to be able to handle that much data, and as other users have suggested you will have to add means to filter down the dataset initially for the user - probably using multiple form postbacks, querystrings or more likely ajax requests

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it to implement it in any other possible ways

Answer (score 0):

I can't apparently leave a comment yet, otherwise I would do that. But I would suggest if at all possible, you need to do some pre-filtering.

Are there absolutely no selections you could ask the user to make first that would reduce the size of this dropdown?

Some thoughts (Random, as I don't know what your data set is):

- Country/State
- Industry
- Date Range
- Manual input filter
- Etc.

Comment: I have two huge xml files which has 300,000 + ID's and User has to select an ID so that the solution will pick up tags corresponding to the ID selected from two files(Before and after change) and will compare so ID selection is a filter to extract require data

Comment: Does the user already know the Id they are looking for? Could it be an ajax'd autocomplete dropdown?

Something like this: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

A browser will be most unhappy about rendering 300k items in a dropdown, and I would imagine a user would be likewise unhappy scrolling through such a list.

Comment: User need not scroll through the dropdown. Within the iist of ID's user can select any id that he wants to verify the data corresponding to that ID so I cannot really filter and show only some ID's.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a dynamic dropdown with search box, the items list will update via ajax when the user types some characters in it.

See https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to post a sample of each of the two files? Doesn't have to contain actual data, just dummy values to understand schema.

FYI, I think your statement `I have two huge xml files which has 300,000 + ID's and User has to select an ID` must be wrong. In such cases the best way to look into the problem is question is not 'select and ID' but 'the user has to select an entry and the ID will be used by the solution to do something else'. As others have pointed out, expecting a user to select from a 300K+ list or expect a page to load the list is a definite usability issue.